# login theme after suspend

Tags: login, suspend, themes

Tried to find other similar questions, but didn't find any.

```
Ubuntu (18.04.2)
```

When booting Ubuntu, at the login panel, i have applied an theme, and everything is working fine.
The problem is that, when i wake up Ubuntu from suspend mode, the login panel is still the default one that Ubuntu use.

tried to change the LogDialogGroup with:

```
#lockDialogGroup {
background: #2c001e url(file:///home/wsu/Pictures/Wallpapers/astronomy.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}
```

Important: That changed the the login screen background image, but takes effect after the second time that i have to login, when the computer comes out of suspend mode. When loging in for first time (bootup login) the login screen is: [image: login]

[image]

After the first time, when i have to login again, that's the screen: [image: next login]

Simply explained, i want to see the first screen every time that i login.

Result from `env | grep DESKTOP_SESSION`: [image]

i followed the instructions from there to apply the login theme: https://github.com/daniruiz/flat-remix-gnome/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Which theme did you apply? The first login screen is GDM3, while the lock screen is GNOME. You only applied a GDM3 theme.

Comment: i have applied the flat-remix login theme. Tried to search "Gnome login theme" on google, but the results is for GDM themes only. What i can do ?

Comment: @Alex search for "gnome shell themes".

Comment: There seems to be a [flat-remix gnome shell theme](https://github.com/daniruiz/flat-remix-gnome/blob/master/README.md) as well.

Comment: @AlexKalaidjiev this bug is fixed in 19.04

Comment: @PRATAP yes, that's what i mean. and no, when i bootup the system, the image is the one that the theme uses. every next time that i have to log in, the astronomy is as background but without the theme.

Comment: @danzel i am still using that theme atm. I got exactly that login screen.

Comment: Hey.. thats nice..can you run this command `env | grep DESKTOP_SESSION` and provide the output? so you added PPA and the install flatremixgnome rite?

Comment: @PRATAP , done.

Comment: ok.. understood.. last detail required.. run `sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css` and notedown what is given for *

Answer (score 2):

Please note that this answer is for this particular case/ Question only after having the comments and outputs..

***Login-Screen theming***

Login Screen is themed by the file `/etc/alternatives/gdm3.css` this is a linked file and not the actual file..

to know which file is used you can use two ways..

1. `ls -l /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css`

Example:

```
parrot@i7-4770U:~$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 56 May 25 08:06 /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css -> /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css
parrot@i7-4770U:~$
```

from the above output it is observed that `.../Flat-Remix/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css` is the one used at login screen..

2. run `sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css` and look for the * mark

Example:

```
parrot@i7-4770U:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css
[sudo] password for parrot: 
There are 12 choices for the alternative gdm3.css (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css).

  Selection    Path                                                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css                        20        auto mode
  1            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/P1.css                                             15        manual mode
  2            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css                                         10        manual mode
  3            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-Dark-fullPanel/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css         17        manual mode
  4            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-Dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css                   17        manual mode
  5            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-Darkest-fullPanel/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css      17        manual mode
  6            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-Darkest/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css                17        manual mode
  7            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-Miami-Dark-fullPanel/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css   17        manual mode
  8            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-Miami-Dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css             17        manual mode
  9            /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-Miami-fullPanel/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css        17        manual mode
  10           /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-Miami/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css                  17        manual mode
  11           /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix-fullPanel/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css              17        manual mode
  12           /usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css                        20        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

So it is clear that login screen .css file can be found in these above two ways and thus editing it will make required changes for login screen only..

***Unlock-Screen theming***

this depends upon the Desktop Session you are using..

to know which desktop session you are using, you can run the below command

`env | grep DESKTOP_SESSION`

Example:

```
parrot@i7-4770U:~$ env | grep DESKTOP_SESSION
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
parrot@i7-4770U:~$
```

from the above output it is observed that the DESKTOP_SESSION is ubuntu which is the default one..

for the default desktop session in Ubuntu 18.04 the style sheet is defined in the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/ubuntu.json`

So open the file in a terminal with the below command

`nano /usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/ubuntu.json`

Example:

```
{
    "parentMode": "user",
    "stylesheetName": "ubuntu.css",
    "enabledExtensions": ["ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com", "ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com"]
}
```

in the above ubuntu.css means `/usr/share/gnome-shell/themes/ubuntu.css` is the file for both default Shell Theme and for Unlock-Screen..

so, to have the same effect of login screen theming on Unlock-screen.. we have two options..

either changing the file  name/path `ubuntu.css` or replacing the contents in ubuntu.css with the flat-remix-gnome which is used at login screen..

in this particular case the best option is to change the file name/path like this by editing `/usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/ubuntu.json`

```
{
    "parentMode": "user",
    "stylesheetName": "Flat-Remix/gnome-shell.css",
    "enabledExtensions": ["ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com", "ubuntu-appindicators@ubunt$
}
```

this means default shell theme and unlock-screen both uses this Flat-Remix/gnome-shell.css file..

So for login screen theming you have to open the file with below command

`sudo -H gedit /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css`

and for unlock-screen/ default shell theme

`sudo -H gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Flat-Remix/gnome-shell.css`

[image]

Comment: Worked ! Thanks for your time !

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Deserve another useful point.